# Call to a member function setOption() on a non-object in Symfony Form Configuration

Tags: php, forms, symfony-1.4

I am trying to add some extra fields to my form and database. I am getting the below error.

**Fatal error: Call to a member function setLabel() on a non-object in "Form.Class.php"**

**Setattribute** error also getting while use SetAttribute for same field.

Code:

```
$this->widgetSchema['purchased_hours']->setLabel('Purchased hours');
$this->widgetSchema['purchased_hours']->setAttribute('size', 50);
```

Can you please tell me the reason why?

Comment: Is $this->widgetSchema['purchased_hours'] a valid object? The error you are getting suggests that its not.

Comment: @Chausser, Thanks for your quick response. Yes, $this->widgetSchema is existed object. I tried to add extra fields(Purchased Hours) to same object.

Comment: what type of object is $this->widgetSchema? Is it an entity? A FormBuilder? or something else?

Comment: Actually I am working on QDPM software. Adding some extra fields to existed form. i.e FormBuilder.

Comment: With the info you have provided there is not enough there to help you. We need to know what $this->widgetSchema is, Where you are trying to add 'purchased_hours'.

Comment: If you have idea about QDPM, you may know about Projects Module in Qdpm. In that Add new project form i am trying to add new fields.

Comment: http://qdpm.net/ ? according to that its build on the symfony1.4 frameword not 2.x. So sadly im not going to be able to help you.

Comment: @Chausser, Thanks for your support. I will try to resolve this one.